# Is a Raspberry Pi 2 a suitable piece of hardware to run a Quorum Node with Tessera? If so has it been done?

Tags: go-ethereum, quorum, raspberry-pi

I would like to set up some Quorum nodes (5) for test purposes and thus far have been unsuccessful in getting a node to run on a Pi 2. The work has stopped due to the need to recompile the binaries from quorum to run on ARM and not as they are on Intel. The Haskell for the constellation isn't playing nicely.

Has anyone attempted or managed this type of deployment?

Thanks in advance for your time in replying!

Comment: Don't have an actual answer, but this might be of use -> https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/661

Answer (score 1):

As per my reply on Slack:

There's a ticket with some info on it [here](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/661).

You may also find this [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64kMWxTaXw8) useful.